# Copying Selected Information from Internet Explorer

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, copy-paste

I've created a IE based VBA script in Excel using. The VBA script opens up IE, navigates to a web site, logs in to the site, enters in search criteria and opens a new window. I used the function GetIE to mirror that new windows website back to the original instance of IE so the VBA script can stay focused on the original instance. It then clicks a link on that window and then highlights some pricing information. But that's where I'm stuck. I desperately need code that will simply copy what i've highlighted to my clipboard. Here is the code posted:

```
Sub ExtractPMDPricing()

Dim core As ICore
Set core = New OpenTwebstLib.core
Dim IE As InternetExlorer
Set IE = CreateObject("Internet Explorer")
Dim browser As IBrowser


Set browser = core.StartBrowser("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")

Range("A1").Select
Selection.Copy

Call browser.FindElement("div", "id=footer-position-placeholder").Click
Call browser.FindElement("a", "uiname=log in, index=1").Click
Call browser.FindElement("input text", "id=erznr").InputText(ActiveCell.Value)
Call browser.FindElement("td", "index=2").Click
Call browser.FindElement("input button", "id=sub").Click
Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:06 AM#)

Call GetIE

Call browser.FindElement("span", "id=selectionctrl_MATCONTSMALLCTRL_navigatorctrl_treeselectionctrl_MATCONTSMALLCTRL_navigatorctrl_Prices-cnt-start").Click
Call browser.FindElement("input text", "id=selectionctrl_MATCONTSMALLCTRL_subcatviewerctrl_selectionctrl_mod_ergebnis_ga[1].kbetr").RightClick
txt = IE.document.parentWindow.clipboardData.GetData("TEXT")
Range("B2").Select
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial
End Sub

' ZVI:2011-05-30 VBA Macro For Already Open IE Window
' Reference required: Tools - References - Microsoft Internet Controls
Function GetIE()

Dim shellWins As ShellWindows
Dim IE As InternetExplorer

Set shellWins = New ShellWindows

If shellWins.Count > 0 Then
' Get IE
Set IE = shellWins.Item(0)
Else
' Create IE
Set IE = New InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = False
End If

IE.Navigate "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

Set IE = Nothing
Set shellWins = Nothing

End Function
```

The copy code I need should fit in right below the last Call browser.findelement line before the end of the sub above Range ("B2").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
txt=ie.document.parentwindow.clipboardData.GetData("TEXT")
```

this gets clipboard. Use Setdata.

Also you can give browser commands.

Executes a command on an OLE object and returns the status of the command execution using the IOleCommandTarget interface. (ie in basic `ie.execwb 5, 0`)

**Syntax**

```
object.ExecWB( _
    cmdID As OLECMDID, _
    cmdexecopt As OLECMDEXECOPT, _
    [pvaIn As Variant,] _
    [pvaOut As Variant])
```

**Parameters**

cmdID
Long that represents the identifier of the command to execute. For more information on command identifiers, see MSHTML Command Identifiers.

cmdexecopt

OLECMDEXECOPT value that specifies the command options.

pvaIn
Optional. A Variant used for specifying command input arguments.

pvaOut
Optional. A Variant used for specifying command output arguments.

```
IDM_COPY Command ID

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Copies the current selection to the clipboard.

C++ Information

Command group CGID_MSHTML (defined in mshtmhst.h)  
Symbolic constant IDM_COPY  
User interface None. Set nCmdExecOpt to OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER. 
IOleCommandTarget::Exec parameters pvaIn Set to NULL. 
pvaOut Set to NULL. 

Header file mshtmcid.h  
Applies to IHTMLDocument2::execCommand, IHTMLDocument2::queryCommandEnabled, IHTMLDocument2::queryCommandIndeterm, IHTMLDocument2::queryCommandState, IHTMLDocument2::queryCommandSupported, IHTMLDocument2::queryCommandValue, IOleCommandTarget::Exec, IOleCommandTarget::QueryStatus.  

Minimum Availability

Internet Explorer 4.0 and later.
```

Comment: PS Programmers aren't allowed to use the clipboard, only users. You should put it in the other program direct.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Noodles! I've a lot more experience in non-web based macros so this has really been a doozy for me. I usually have some type of script recorder available to base any code additions needed so I've been going off pure references from web sites. It's almost working now...I can just feel it. However when I run the macro now, its referencing the top line of code you provided and giving me the classic **runtime error 424 - object required error code**. I'm playing with the browser commands as well, pretty interesting. Any more help would be great, thanks again!

Comment: Set ie = createObject("Internet Explorer").

Comment: Dim IE As InternetExplorer **And** Set IE = CreateObject("Internet Explorer") **Then** txt = IE.document.parentWindow.clipboardData.GetData("clipboard") **But** it's still not working...my computer hates me.. Any suggestions?

Comment: I just updated the original code to look AS IS in my macro with your suggestions. It's still not recognizing the txt code you gave me. Am i missing something small? Thanks so much.

Comment: I called it IE but in your code you called the same object browser - so `browser.document.parentWindow.clipboardData.GetData("clipboard")`

Comment: do you think that I could make this a function and just call it in the main code?

Comment: Better yet, @noodles I think i'm missing a reference from Tools--> References in VBA. it just isnt recognizing the _txt_ part in your code. Any suggestions? I've got everything else finished. I just need this copy function!